# Python: open zip file without extension of ".zip"

Tags: python, zip

I have a zip file called "main.zip". Inside that, I have another zip called "meta" which does not have the ".zip" extension. I want to open the "meta" zip file which contains lots of text files. But when I try to open the "meta" zip file, I get an error saying `zipfile.BadZipfile: File is not a zip file`. Below is my code:

```
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(inputZipFile, 'r')
print(zf.namelist())    # [u'meta']
zf2 = zipfile.ZipFile(zf.open('meta')) # throws error
```

I can't extract and open "meta" because I want to do this entirely in memory without writing to the disk.

My ultimate goal is to modify one of the text files and output  a new zip.

Comment: What about `tempfile`?

Comment: Is it just the extension, or is `meta` perhaps corrupted?
Compare opening zip files with and without the extension.  What happens?

Comment: @Prune I tried opening `meta` with .zip and it opened perfectly. And it's not currepted. I need to open it just as it is cuz I get the file from somewhere else.

Comment: @JaredGoguen I don't want to extract at all, for temp file I will have to extract it first.

Comment: I can reproduce this issue with known-good zip files.

Comment: The extension is not the issue here, you are passing a `ZipExtFile` to `zipfile.ZipFile`.

Comment: @JaredGoguen Per the documentation that should work though. `ZipFile.open` produces a "binary file-like object" which is what `zipfile.Zipfile` expects. I proposed a workaround as an answer below.

Comment: @AdamSmith yup, just noticed that and was checking if an intermediate buffer would remedy the situation (as your answer uses)

Comment: Whoops, this is a clearcut dupe with an exact copy of my answer by the venerable Martijn Pieters. I've hammered this to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're intent on doing this in memory, you need to create a file-like object to call `zipfile.ZipFile` on. Although [`ZipFile.open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html?highlight=zipfile#zipfile.ZipFile.open) says that it does this, in practice I'm getting the same error you are.

What I've gotten to work is to read the binary with [`ZipFile.read`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html?highlight=zipfile#zipfile.ZipFile.read) and toss it into a [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=stringio#io.BytesIO) stream.

```
import io

with zipfile.ZipFile("main.zip") as zf:
    f2 = io.BytesIO(zf.read("meta"))
    with zipfile.ZipFile(f2) as zf2:
        # this is inside the inner zip file
```

Comment: That worked like magic. Seriously, I have been trying something similar since hours with `StringIO` but it didn't work. `BytesIO` did the job. Thank you

Comment: Hi @ParthBhoiwala ! i have the same situation as yours. Just that I just need to extract the files out of meta and thats it. I am not able to extract the files in meta. Can you help?